# Crop particular part of image in android

Tags: android, image-processing, bitmap, crop, android-image

I want to crop Red part from following image, Is there any simple method available in android that can crop following image.

[image: Sample Image that i want to crop]

I have found many SO questions but all are suggesting to used following code:

```
Bitmap croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOriginal, 100, 100,100, 100);
```

This code work well if width & height are around 2MP resolution, but if that cropped part is more than 3MP resolution than application got crashed with OOM error.

Is there any way that handle image more than 3MP during cropping?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can used following code that can solve your problem.

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postScale(0.5f, 0.5f);
Bitmap croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOriginal, 100, 100,100, 100, matrix, true);
```

Above method do postScalling of image before cropping, so you can get best result with cropped image without getting OOM error.

For more detail you can refer [this blog](http://coderzheaven.com/2011/03/crop-an-image-in-android/)

Comment: what is the use of postScale?

Answer (score 2):

1- Change your imageview for bitmap

```
final Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.img);
```

2-use your bitmap to crop what you want

```
Bitmap croppedBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, x, y , width , height);
```

3-Take care x,y from Top and left

4- to preview your bitmap again in your imageview

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(croppedBmp);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to crop image in any shape OR only selected part then 
you can use ready made [open source library](https://github.com/choiboi/android-cropping-example)