# need example of cropping an image in android app

Tags: android, crop

Sorry for the not technical question.

I am researching to understand how can I implement a very common feature in android apps where the user can crop a part of an image. This is usually performed using a square window hovering above the shadowed image. A good example is with choosing profile image in the linkedin app.
Does anyone know or have good example of how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9747295/crop-particular-part-of-image-in-android

Comment: There are lots of questions and answers about this. Hope this one will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15228812/crop-image-android-android

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the sample method below. Not only you can cut a **rectangle** but **ANY SHAPE** from any place in the bitmap you want.

You can cut a **Micky mouse** from the center of bitmap also.

The below method is cutting a rectangular bitmap to have pointed triangle on the left side of bitmap. like whatsapp do for thumbnails of images shared in chat.

Anything drawn from the Paint with **setXfermode(new PoterDuffXfermode(Mode.CLEAR))**  will clear the pixels from bitmap.

Try it out.. Hope this helps :)

```
private Bitmap cropAndGivePointedShape(Bitmap originalBitmap)
    {
        Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalBitmap.getWidth(),
                                               originalBitmap.getHeight(),
                                               Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.CLEAR));              
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay); 
        canvas.drawBitmap(originalBitmap, 0, 0, null); 
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, 20, 20, p);

        Point a = new Point(0, 20);
        Point b = new Point(20, 20);
        Point c = new Point(0, 40);

        Path path = new Path();
        path.setFillType(FillType.EVEN_ODD);
        path.lineTo(b.x, b.y);
        path.lineTo(c.x, c.y);
        path.lineTo(a.x, a.y);
        path.close();

        canvas.drawPath(path, p);

        a = new Point(0, 40);
        b = new Point(0, 60);
        c = new Point(20, 60);

        path = new Path();
        path.setFillType(FillType.EVEN_ODD);
        path.lineTo(b.x, b.y);
        path.lineTo(c.x, c.y);
        path.lineTo(a.x, a.y);
        path.close();

        canvas.drawPath(path, p);

        canvas.drawRect(0, 60, 20, originalBitmap.getHeight(), p);

        return bmOverlay;
    }
```

Comment: how can i draw dragable semi transparent circle over imageview like whatsapp facebook and other app doing while selecting profile picture. then your give method will work for me.Any idea

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

### 1. Manifest XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="camera.test.demo"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<activity
android:name=".SimpleCameraGalleryDemo"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

**2. Activity Code:**

-

```
package camera.test.demo;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class SimpleCameraGalleryDemo extends Activity {
private static final int PICK_FROM_CAMERA = 1;
private static final int PICK_FROM_GALLERY = 2;
ImageView imgview;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

imgview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
Button buttonCamera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_take_camera);
Button buttonGallery = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_select_gallery);
buttonCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {
// call android default camera
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.toString());
// ******** code for crop image
intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
intent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
intent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
intent.putExtra("outputY", 150);

try {

intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);

} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
// Do nothing for now
}
}
});
buttonGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Intent intent = new Intent();
// call android default gallery
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
// ******** code for crop image
intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
intent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
intent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
intent.putExtra("outputY", 150);

try {

intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
"Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_GALLERY);

} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
// Do nothing for now
}
}
});
}
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_CAMERA) {
Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");
imgview.setImageBitmap(photo);

}
}

if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLERY) {
Bundle extras2 = data.getExtras();
if (extras2 != null) {
Bitmap photo = extras2.getParcelable("data");
imgview.setImageBitmap(photo);

}
}
}
}
```

**3. Main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textViewAddCard"
android:layout_width="250dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:text="Take Image"
android:textSize="16dp"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center"
android:typeface="sans"/>

<Button
android:id="@+id/btn_take_camera"
android:layout_width="250dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:text="Take From Camera"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:typeface="sans"/>

<Button
android:id="@+id/btn_select_gallery"
android:layout_width="250dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:text="Select from Gallery"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:typeface="sans" />
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView1"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Refer Link <http://www.androidhub4you.com/2012/07/how-to-crop-image-from-camera-and.html>

Comment: Also refer link : <http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/capture-and-crop-an-image-with-the-device-camera--mobile-11458>

Comment: The code says NullPointerException on this line  Bundle extras = data.getExtras();........?

Answer (score 1):

Try this library:

https://github.com/biokys/cropimage

For a square:

```
intent.putExtra(CropImage.ASPECT_X, 2);
intent.putExtra(CropImage.ASPECT_Y, 2);
```

For a rectangle:

```
intent.putExtra(CropImage.ASPECT_X, 3);
intent.putExtra(CropImage.ASPECT_Y, 2);
```