# When capturing webview, content without displaying view is white

Tags: android, webview, capture

i have a question about Webview.

It`s my source and result.

```
private void saveDocumentImage() {

    WebView wv = arrWebView.get(0);

    wv.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    int y=wv.getHeight();

    Bitmap captureView = Bitmap.createBitmap(wv.getMeasuredWidth(), wv.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    wv.layout(0, 0, wv.getMeasuredWidth(), wv.getMeasuredHeight());
    Canvas screenShotCanvas = new Canvas(captureView);
    wv.draw(screenShotCanvas);


    if (captureView != null) {
        try {
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            OutputStream fOut = null;
            File file = new File(path, "temp");

            if (!file.exists())
                file.mkdirs();

            fOut = new FileOutputStream(path + "/temp/test_0.jpg");
            captureView.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut);
            wv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    wv.destroyDrawingCache();
    captureView.recycle();
    captureView=null;
}
```

and here is same as mine.
 : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37023619/capturing-bitmap-android-chromium-webview-returns-content-as-white

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U can't take screen shot of  web view and surface view because their content is loaded in their holders and holder is not a view. If you find a way then share it. Once i did a little research on it and found [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/monkeyrunner/MonkeyImage.html) But I haven't tested it yet. try it if it works for you then Accept my answer :D. best Of luck

Comment: Thanks for ur intention. and I solved it  now. lol

I need to option 'webview.enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw();' and I found it from android developer. 

and I got a new problem. lol could u help me??
I want to crop the whole view but It didn`t work... It is my source

I added it for cropping. 
'bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0,2000, wv.getMeasuredWidth(), 4000);'
 and I hope the bitmap appear from 2000 to 4000 (x cooperate.), but It appear from 0 to 4000....

Comment: createBitmap(Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height)
createBitmap(bitmap, 0,2000, wv.getMeasuredWidth(), 4000);
last two parameters will decide the height and width of newly created bitmap u can get your help from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9747295/crop-particular-part-of-image-in-android 
http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/03/15/crop-an-image-in-android/

Comment: especially from this one  http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/03/15/crop-an-image-in-android/

Comment: Thanks for link, Adeel Turk .  I solved it but why It was not working well 2 days ago... then I try yesterday it was working well even I didn't fix anything... lol but ur link is really helpful to me. 

c.f.>,  webview.enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw(); <- I solved it using this option. Thanks.

Comment: My pleasure Adrian. :D aliens might know this . i am also facing a same issue tomorrow my code was going good but now same code same device but Gurr#%$&#@@@ :@  :/.

Comment: hahaha I can guess what u feel... lol It`s crazy thing. same code and same device but one is nice and the other is bad. lol crazy!!!!!!!!!!! or I`m hottest foolish!!

Comment: :D yeah. Best of luck dude coz we need it most of the time